# Cannot Join to AD DC via samba

Tags: active-directory, samba, domain-controller

I'm trying to join my CentOS 7,64 bit server to an AD DC and I'm using the following command:

```
# net ads join -U <username> -S <target server>
Enter <username's> password:
```

But after long time, I get

```
Failed to join domain: failed to find DC for domain <name>
```

I'm not sure whats the issue. But I have another server of same specs connected to this AD DC successfully.

I guess it could be the network issue, because from the another server ( which is already joined ) I am able to telnet to port 389 and 53 of AD DC. But from this server I cannot telnet those ports of AD DC server but just ping.

So is this issue due to network ( port block ) or something else? I assure that both server has similar config files.

Answer (score 2):

> But from this server I cannot telnet those ports of AD DC server but
>   just ping.

Then problem **at least** in network connection. Check the [document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/179442) that you have opened all needed ports between the client and AD DC.